# How to know two process ids in "tail -f filename.dat | nc localhost 36000 &"

Tags: bash, shell, unix

As described in the title, I want to know the process id of `tail` and `nc`.

It is easy to use `$!` to get the pid of `nc`, but how about `tail`?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sobrique I wanna kill both processes by their pid when something is done.

Answer (score 0):

From comments - you're wanting to terminate these processes once a separate event occurs.

Try a subshell. (`cat -v` in the below for my testing)

e.g.

```
( tail -f /path_to_file/ | cat -v ) & echo $!
```

This will give you a pid of a spawned subshell, which you can kill and get your sub processes at the same time.